# Combining single cell LIPO chargers into a multi-cell charger

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo, circuit-design

I have a [2S lipo battery](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__23821__Turnigy_nano_tech_3000mAh_2S2P_20_40C_Lipo_Receiver_Pack.html) that I want to charge. Normally, I'd charge it with a balanced 2S lipo charger like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CF93RF4), but for my application, I want to embed the charger in the device, and consumer chargers are too big.

I also don't want to design my own balanced 2S charger from scratch.

I have several super cheap tiny single-cell lipo chargers like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D8UZL9E). Is it possible to combine two of these to make a 2S balanced charger?

The circuit I'm thinking of would look something like this:

[image]

Would this work? Is there anything I'm missing? Should I put schottky diodes between the charger output and the positive cell terminal?

Comment: No, this won't work, because the "Cell 2 charger" is charging one cell, but the "Cell 1 charger" is charging both cells.

Comment: @uint128_t, I've corrected the circuit.

Comment: the two USB ports would have to be floating (i.e. unconnected) to each other.. which seems more of a hassle than a solution

Comment: @WesleyLee, Why would they have to be unconnected?

Comment: Because the input grounds and the output grounds of the charger would most likely be connected and if they went to non-isolated USB ports (which also have their grounds connected) the Cell 2 would get shorted out as the ground of Cell charger 1 would be connected to the main ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes potentially it will work, but 
**it will not work if both USB power inputs are connected together**

if you use individual AC to USB adapters ("phone chargers" or similar) it will work,  but if you try to connect both Li-poly chargers to the same USB supply you'll have `gnd` on both Li-poly chargers connected together. if you follow the lines you'll see that that would short-circuit cell2.

Comment: I see your point. If I want to use a common input supply for both chargers, such as the external 8.4V, what's the solution? Is there any way to isolate them?

Comment: I think it would be simpler to use a two cell charger.